# Why doesn't my JQuery code work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that doesn't seem to work. I would think that this should give me an alert the instant I scroll, but no. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        alert("hi!");
    )};
});
```

Comment: *Always* have your browser's developer console open when testing new code.

Comment: Beginners! It's time to press F12 to use the console before asking question like this on SO whenever something isn't working!

Comment: I did, the console wasn't showing anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error with bracket line 4 - correct code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        alert("hi!");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SLQj2/

Comment: missed that..anyway op, next time post your errors as well, you can't do javascript right without a console open to watch for errors.

Answer (score 1):

just typo: )};  should be  });

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this and works fine. Any errors in your console?

`$(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
    console.log('Event Fired');
});`

Comment: Probably a comment, unless you're specifically saying that `on` works and the `scroll` function doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        alert("hi!");
    });<---- please pay attention here!
});
```

you need a js editer(good editer can help you avoiding simple mistake)